# VBA numbering loop

Tags: vba, loops

I am trying to simplify a code in a Macro for numbering rows of specific columns of excel. Currently I am using

```
With Sheet1.Range("V6")
.Value = 1
.AutoFill .Resize(V6 + C, 1), xlFillSeries
End With
```

The macro has already set "C" as a variable that can change each time it is run. I want to simplify the code because I don't know how to loop this to repeat in every third column. I have tried For Loops but i am new to VBA and cannot get the program to run. Looping this would help me becasue I currently have this same code altered 85 differnt times to fill 85 different columns. For example, the next set is

```
With Sheet1.Range("Y6")
.Value = 1
.AutoFill .Resize(Y6 + C, 1), xlFillSeries
End With
```

Is there a more simple way this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate approach using `Offset` to fill every third column, starting in `V6`.

```
Sub MyNumbering()
    Dim c As Long, i As Long

    c = 100

    For i = 0 To 84
        With Sheet1.Range("V6").Offset(, i * 3)
            .Value = 1
            .AutoFill .Resize(c), xlFillSeries
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This will iterate every 3rd column starting with column V and post 85 columns of row numbers starting in row 6 and ending at `C + 6`

```
Sub mynum()

Dim c As Long: c = 100

Dim j As Long
For j = 22 To 22 + 85 * 3 Step 3
    With Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(6, j), Sheet1.Cells(c + 6, j))
        .Formula = "=ROW(1:1)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
Next j
End Sub
```